# Java Lucene IndexSearcher.explain for filtered queries

Tags: java, lucene, lucene-filters

Given a Lucene `Query query` I can get an explanation of the results and scoring by calling something like this:

```
TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, 10);
ScoreDoc[] hits = results.scoreDocs;
searcher.explain(query, hits[idx].doc);
```

great!

Is there an equivalent for filtered queries?

If I plug in an `org.apache.lucene.search.Filter filter` like this:

```
TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, filter, 10);
```

How can I explain the results of the query above?

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you're trying to achieve. When you're asking for a particular document to be explained, you're doing so with your search query and a document ID. Filter is irrelevant to the explanation, **as it only narrows down the total amount of hits by eliminating documents not matching the filters provided**, and not by changing your actual query. So to sum it up, filters have no impact on the actual explanation of a specific document in regards to the query performed upon it. See below:

```
TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, filter, 10); // Apply filter here.
ScoreDoc[] hits = results.scoreDocs;
for(ScoreDoc hit : hits)
  {
  searcher.explain(query, hit.doc); // Filter won't affect this either way.
  }
```